# Deploying appfuse app on cloudbees as war

Tags: cloudbees

I have appfuse maven project , is it better to deploy it using Click start Tomcat or as a Jenkin Maven project? I have tried both but it does not seem to be working in any ways. I have created database and bound it to the app. still it gives error for spring bean creation etc. Can anyone help in this scenario?

Answer (score 0):

If I would need to deploy my appfuse maven application on CloudBees platform, I will try two different ways:

1. Use the Tomcat 7 Maven ClickStart as a template changing the SCM to your repo.
2. Use the [CloudBees SDK](http://wiki.cloudbees.com/bin/view/RUN/BeesSDK) to deploy your application.

In this last case, you just need to generate your .war file, in case you use maven, launching:

```
mvn clean package
```

And then you can deploy your application from the CLoudBees SDK using:

```
bees app:deploy -t tomcat7 -a APPID MYFILE.war
```

You say that when you deploy your application it gives error for spring bean creation. However, you don't attach any stacktrace to your question, so it is difficult to do any kind of diagnosis on our end.